# How to reference a temporary table in a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I have a local table variable in a stored procedure, containing a couple of columns; I need to update column 2 of each row with the result of a subquery based on the value of column 1 for that row.

Something like:

```
UPDATE @mytable
SET column2 = (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE something = @mytable.column1)
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I get an error about @mytable being undefined.

What is the correct syntax for this query?

Comment: Where are you calling this statement? From inside the stored procedure?

Comment: Yes. Both the temp table and the statement are in the same SP.

Comment: @ doesn't indicate a temp table, it indicates a variable of type TABLE. # is for temp tables (#mytable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using an ALIAS?

```
UPDATE temp 
SET temp.column2 = (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE something = temp.column1) 
FROM @mytable temp
```

Comment: It would need to be `UPDATE temp SET temp.column2 = (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE something = temp.column1) from @mytable temp`